# Basic / Assembler startup code (C64)

Tags: commodore-64, 6502

I'm just creating my own `.prg` file using [NCurses Hexeditor](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/hexedit.1.html) in Ubuntu which I load using `load"file.prg",8` in Vice. I followed the information in [this link](https://michaelcmartin.github.io/Ophis/book/x72.html) explaining how to create a `.prg` file. It says basic starts at 2048 ($0800) but loads the `.prg` code starting at $0801:

| Memory Locations | Value |
| --- | --- |
| $0801–$0802 | 2-byte pointer to the next line of BASIC code ($080C). |
| $0803–$0804 | 2-byte line number ($000A = 10). |
| $0805 | Byte code for the SYS command. |
| $0806–$080A | The rest of the line, which is just the string " 2064". |
| $080B | Null byte, terminating the line. |
| $080C–$080D | 2-byte pointer to the next line of BASIC code ($0000 = end of program). |

Is there any reason for this? I tried it at $0800 and all works fine (see below). I guess it wouldn't matter because the Assembly code starts at 2064 ($0810), but just thought I might be missing something as to why they chose $0801 and not $0800.

**What I tried**

First of all, according to the C64 Programmer's Reference Guide (C64PRM, p.59):

> Programs will LOAD starting at memory location 2048 unless a secondary <address> of 1 is used. If you use the secondary address of 1 this will cause the program to LOAD to the memory location from which it was saved.

Tests show that no matter what PRG header I use my bytes are always loaded into 2048 when using `,8` as per C64PRM. But let's just suppose I use a header for $0800, then I have the following bytes in Hexeditor:

```
00000000  00 08 0B 08  0A 00 9E 20   32 30 36 34  00 00 00 00   ....... 2064....
00000010  00 EE 20 D0  4C 10 08                                 .. .L..
```

and I don't get an error, e.g.:

[image]

Comment: I think that if you look at the monitor after loading your program you will see that it is actually loaded at $0801.

Comment: @BrianH yes the monitor seems to show everything stored at $0801 and the next BASIC instruction pointer is automatically incremented. Strange, but there it is.

Comment: FWIW, I looked at the reason for $0800 vs. $0801 in Applesoft, which is also a Microsoft BASIC; see https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/20180/56

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not strictly true that "all works fine" for machine-language programs with a standard BASIC header starting at $0800 vice $0801. The idea of the BASIC header is that your program is easily loaded and then started using the `RUN` command:

```
LOAD"MYPROG",8 REM NOTE ABSENCE OF ",1"
RUN
```

If you move the header one-byte down to $0800, then BASIC no longer parses it correctly. Your line number will be messed up, and `RUN`ing your program will likely return `?SYNTAX  ERROR`. It is true that your actual machine code is unaffected and you could still start it with the appropriate `SYS` command manually entered. But the desire is for it to work by just using the standard `LOAD` & `RUN`. Screen shot below shows this for a quick & dirty test program I created to load at $0800. The list of the program *should read as*:

```
2020 SYS 4864
```

Looking at the disassembly of Commodore BASIC v2, this assumption of the actual first line being at $0801 is probably related to the fact that the `RUN` command is a special case of the `GOTO` command. Because of this, I think the first byte is skipped just to simplify the coding of the interpreter.

[image: Demonstration in VICE of the above, resulting in an error message: ?SYNTAX ERROR IN 58376]

Comment: Thanks @BrianH I'm a little uncertain as the C64 Programmers Reference Manual says that programs will LOAD into 2048 unless the secondary address `,8,1` is used. And if I change my PRG header to anything I like, it always loads into 2048 when I use `,8` and I don't get the corrupt line number or crash you show above.

Comment: No it does not load to $0800 (2048) if the secondary address is not given, it loads to $0801 (2049), always.

Comment: @Retrograde yes, the monitor seems show everything stored at $0801 and the next BASIC instruction pointer is automatically incremented. Strange, but there it is.

Comment: It seems the C64 Programmers Reference Manual is wrong in saying that programs will LOAD to 2048. Many other publications describes it correctly (with load start at $0801 or 2049). There is some confusion about the start of the BASIC program area which is actually $0800, but on the first location a 0 is needed because the RUN command starts with the BASIC text pointer pointing to the last read character. This 0 byte provides an end-of-line condition, which let the interpreter search for the next line (an implicit GOTO 0) and advance to $801 as the first line to interpret.

Comment: @JohannKlasek Thanks. That explanation makes sense with what I was also seeing in the BASIC interpreter source code.

Answer (score 3):

When you do a `LOAD"MYPROG",8` on C64, the computer will relocate the program to start at $0801 -- ignoring the load address from the file header.

If you do a `LOAD"MYPROG",8,1` it will load the program to the load address specified in the file header.

If you load your test program to `$0800` using the `,8,1` option, my expectation is that it won't be linked correctly by the BASIC interpreter and will not run.